# Fantasy novel about a young guy and girl who find some sort of magic world

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

I remember reading this book so vividly but I have never been able to find it!!

The main characters are teenage-young adult, and they discover this parallel fantasy world. I think there is something to do with a magic scepter, and four magic gemstones that control the four elements. They end up wrapped up in trying to recover these.

I also remember vividly that the girl ends up getting some sort of a 'pearl of truth' from a fairy that lets her know if people are lying. And by the end of the series, that power gets amped up to the point where she is an oracle, prophet, or something of the sort.

The boy I think had some natural affinity for magic making him a wizard or something similar, but it was dangerous for him to use it too much because it was addictive? Or made him angry?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Thank you!! I read this in roughly the 2010s...I would think it was published in the late 1990s-early 2000s but honestly I'm not sure. I also have no idea what the cover looks like. I think it was a trilogy, or a series of books as well though.

Comment: Scott L. Collins's _[Scepter](https://www.goodreads.com/series/102899-scepter)_ series involves the titular object and a few young protagonists on a quest to find four element-themed gems, but I don't think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think this is it...I will try to see if I remember any other details. The part I really vividly remember is the girl becoming an oracle/prophetess at the end bc of the fairy.